# GWT approach for mobile

Tags: gwt, mobile, mgwt

I need to develop a gwt app that requires support on desktop, mobile, tablet. I need to choose whether to use m-gwt or stick to the approach [presented](http://static.googleusercontent.com/media/www.google.com/en//events/io/2011/static/presofiles/cramsdale_DevTools_using-gwt-and-google-plugin-for-eclipse-to-build-greate-mobile-web-apps.pdf) in Google IO 2011

Google IO 2011 approach seems to be - 
1) create different views for different screen sizes 
2) use deferred binding load only the relevant views according to the user agent
3) same presenter code

IO 2011 approach seems much simpler to me (and not tied with activities and places) but I am not sure if this approach is still popular and will work.

Can someone please let me know the pros and cons of these two approaches ?

Regards, 
Sathya

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mistaken in the assumption that mgwt is tied to Activities & Places, you can use it without using them. If you like using Activities and Places mgwt works of course very well.
The approach presented at Google I/O is actually quite similiar on what mgwt does.

If you are looking into building one application for phone, tablet and desktop from one code base here is an interesting read: http://fahnenbruck.blogspot.de/2014/02/running-on-any-platform-using-java-with.html

Comment: Hi Daniel, If I don't use mgwt and stick with the approach mentioned in google IO 2011 - will there be any performance penalties when accessing from mobile device ?